# Facebook video embed code does not working

Tags: facebook, flash, embed

I am trying to embed a facebook video on my website but it gives "Video Unavailable. this video has either has been removed from facebook or is not visible".

video is public to everyone, is not deleted and I can watch it on facebook via other browsers that I am not logged in.

I tried both below embed codes, neither is worked.

## 1

```
<object width="500" height="300">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.facebook.com/v/VIDEO_ID"></param>
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
<embed src="http://www.facebook.com/v/VIDEO_ID" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="500" height="300" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true">
</embed>
</object>
```

## 2

```
<object width="500" height="300">
<param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
<param name="movie" value="http://www.facebook.com/v/VIDEO_ID" />
<embed src="http://www.facebook.com/v/VIDEO_ID" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" width="500 height="300">
</embed>
</object>
```

Any idea?
thanks!

Comment: Please can you reveal the ID of the video?

Comment: I notice that you have a syntax error in your example 2 `<embed>` at `width="500` you're missing a " - but I doubt this is your issue.

Comment: I guess it's c/p problem, not the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works perfectly fine for me.  The video plays whether I'm logged in to Facebook or not:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<object width="500" height="300">
<param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
<embed src="http://www.facebook.com/v/244871308895731" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" width="500 height="300">
</embed>
</object>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem could be down to location or an IP issue.

Comment: I don't think so.as I said in the question, its privacy is set public and I can view it on another computers that I am not even logged in to facebook

Comment: Please can you provide the ID of the video, without it the question is unanswerable.

Comment: Please see this revised answer

Comment: just tried that, and still not working.. as I see you just removed the movie param and replaced video id right?

Comment: I'm beginning to wonder whether it's a country or IP issue or something like that, but I can't imagine that Facebook would have restrictions like that.

Comment: yes I thought about the country or IP restriction but I can watch via "video/video.php?v=" or any other embeedded flash videos in other websites.

Comment: no not working on local machine and I tried uploading a sample html to a domain, that is also not working. I think it is possible a country or IP problem, cause I cannot see any error on embed codes, they are the same as the other peoples on web

Comment: Are you using internet explorer? If so, you need the movie parameter to point to the flash file.

Comment: @box86rowh no I'm using chrome and ff

Answer (score 1):

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/video/embed?video_id=1671900191543" width="420" height="300" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```